# php check empty array

Tags: php

after submited form i want to check array if array is empty alert error for user. but i get error when submited form:

**PHP**

```
    $errors = array_filter($_POST['session']);
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($_POST['session'] as $value) {
            $session.=$value.',';
        }
        $session=substr($session, 0 , -1);
    }

Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\manage\test_bank\index.php on line 729
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check wheather it is an array or not, before doing any array operation.

```
if(is_array($_POST['session'])){
  $errors = array_filter($_POST['session']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning occurs because array_filters() requires an array to be passed to it.  Before passing $_POST['session'] to this function, very if that it is an array:

```
if(is_array($_POST['session'])) {
    $errors = array_filter($_POST['session']);
    // continue on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `is_array`for checking weather it is array or not.

```
echo is_array($_POST['session']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because $_POST is not an array I guess you are looking for this :

`$errors = array_filter($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

The following would most simply check for empty errors or not

```
!empty($_POST['session'])
```

Would work provided you are not stuffing empty entries in the $_POST['session'] in no error cases. Why do you need the array_filter?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `array_filter($_POST)` because $_POST is an assoc array, or check if `$_POST['session']` is an array using this line `is_array($_POST['session'])` before the array_filter().
You should check first if the variable you are working with is an array before using array functions.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an array, but here $_POST['session'] is not.

You can smply try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['session']))
{
    //do your stuff
}
```